# magento 2 : event to capture the cart price rule coupon?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.2.2

How to get the coupon code which customer enters in the checkout page and giving custom discounts to the customer according to the country code using observers.

please help me out.

Comment: `giving custom discounts to the customer` don't understand this word if a coupon is already given discount then why you need custom discount again. Can you please explain it?

Comment: i need one discount for one country and another discount amount for another country with the same coupon code...thats why i need observer to do this

Answer (score -1):

- Create cart price rule with 1 common coupon code and don't specific any country
- Now this coupon code would apply for all customers irrespective of countries
- Then use this event **salesrule_validator_process** and try to debug customer country data then override the cart rule discount based on your conditions